# window.chrome.webview.postmessage from child html to main c++ app (webView2)

Tags: html, c++, webview2

I am using WebView2 for displaying html contents in my win32 application.
I have parent.html in which I am providing reference of child.html like -

```
<frameset id="myFrmset">
        <frame id="myFrm" name="frmContent" src="child.html"></frame> 
</frameset>
```

In child.html :

```
<button id="samplebutton" onclick="postmessagetocode()">clickhere</button>
<script>
function postmessagetocode() {
            window.chrome.webview.postmessage('clickSample');
        }
</script>
```

In my c++ code I am loading parent.htm and want to get above message 'clickSample' in `m_webView->add_WebMessageReceived.`

Issue that I am facing : by doing like above I am not getting this message in code. If I post any message from parent.html then I can get it. But if I do like from child.html then it never come to c++ code.

Is there the way to do so?
Is it something like I need to catch the message at parent.html first then post again to c++?

Thanks.
MChauhan

Comment: First, `frameset`is soooooooo deprecated (for the last 20 years). That's why I don't think `WebView2` supports it. It does support `IFrame` AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use the `add_framecreated` API to capture the `ICoreWebView2Frame2` object.

Then use the `ICoreWebView2Frame2`'s `add_WebMessageReceived` API to get the web messages from that iframe.

references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2_4?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44#add_framecreated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2frame2?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44#add_webmessagereceived